# Filtering page content with Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Attempting to filter out content on the page based on a jQuery UI autocomplete search.
When the user is typing content not related to the search will switch to display: none;
so only the content relevant to the search is displayed.

HTML

```
        <div class="items" data-id="Get Milk">Get Milk on the way home</div>
        <div class="items" data-id="Drop by Phil's">Drop by Phils house</div>
        <div class="items" data-id="Grab a Sandwich">Grab a sandwich</div>

<input id="auto" type="text" />
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {
    var source = $(".items").map(function () {
        return $(this).data("id");
    }).get();

    $("#auto").autocomplete({
        source: source        
    });
});​
```

Attempting with

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var search = $("#auto").html();
    var results = $(".items").html();

    if (search == results) {
        $(".items").css("display", "block");
    } 
    else {
        $(".items").css("display", "none");
    }

});
```

Now I do understand that I need to refer to the individual "items" and this also needs to be demystified.
​
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J5rVP/25/
Courtesy Andrew Whitaker, from [bit.ly/U1gjr2](http://bit.ly/U1gjr2)

Answer (score 1):

OK, first things first is to understand that you are dealing with a jQueryUI Widget.  They are great and extensible, but you will have to dig around in the docs to make sure you understand how they work.

When you init your autocomplete you will want to provide a response function where you can do your checking for matches and hide if you need to.  Like this:

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: source,
    response: function(event, ui){
        if(ui.content.length == 0)
            alert("nothing");
        else
           alert(ui.content.length + " items");
    }
});
```

Lastly, please peruse the autocomplete documentation.  You'll learn a bunch about the jQuery UI API there.

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But how might I alter the CSS of the detected items so that all other items 'display: none;' while the x amount of items picked up 'display: block;'?